# google maps javascript api -- export polygons to kml?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine

I am using the google maps javascript api to make polygons based on user input (I'm not using the Drawing library, just the straight-up v3). I want to be able to export these features to kml. However, there is nothing I can see in the javascript api that allows me to do this.

I know that maps engine lite has an "export to kml" feature.

Is there some google library I am missing that allows for exporting to kml? I've seen some solutions where the polygon's attributes are sent to a textarea and that is used to generate kml, but I'd much prefer using an existing library rather than making my own kml file.

Answer (score 6):

The [Blitz GMap Editor](http://code.google.com/p/blitz-gmap-editor/) allows you to export KML (uses the drawing manager to create and edit them, but you could use your code).

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)

To KML code from [Blitz GMap Editor](http://code.google.com/p/blitz-gmap-editor/).  Depends on [xmlwriter.js](http://blitz-gmap-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/%20blitz-gmap-editor/release/xmlwriter.js)

```
this.toKML = function() {
  var result = mapToObject();
  var xw = new XMLWriter('UTF-8');
  xw.formatting = 'indented'; //add indentation and newlines
  xw.indentChar = ' '; //indent with spaces
  xw.indentation = 2; //add 2 spaces per level

  xw.writeStartDocument();
  xw.writeStartElement('kml');
  xw.writeAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
  xw.writeStartElement('Document');

  for (var i = 0; i < result.overlays.length; i++) {
    xw.writeStartElement('Placemark');
    xw.writeStartElement('name');
    xw.writeCDATA(result.overlays[i].title);
    xw.writeEndElement();
    xw.writeStartElement('description');
    xw.writeCDATA(result.overlays[i].content);
    xw.writeEndElement();
    if (result.overlays[i].type == "marker") {

      xw.writeStartElement('Point');
      xw.writeElementString('extrude', '1');
      xw.writeElementString('altitudeMode', 'relativeToGround');
      xw.writeElementString('coordinates', result.overlays[i].position.lng.toString() + "," + result.overlays[i].position.lat.toString() + ",0");
      xw.writeEndElement();

    } else if (result.overlays[i].type == "polygon" || result.overlays[i].type == "rectangle" || result.overlays[i].type == "circle") {
      xw.writeStartElement('Polygon');
      xw.writeElementString('extrude', '1');
      xw.writeElementString('altitudeMode', 'relativeToGround');

      if (result.overlays[i].type == "rectangle") {
        //its a polygon
        xw.writeStartElement('outerBoundaryIs');
        xw.writeStartElement('LinearRing');
        xw.writeStartElement("coordinates");
        xw.writeString(result.overlays[i].bounds.sw.lng + "," + result.overlays[i].bounds.sw.lat + ",0");
        xw.writeString(result.overlays[i].bounds.ne.lng + "," + result.overlays[i].bounds.sw.lat + ",0");
        xw.writeString(result.overlays[i].bounds.ne.lng + "," + result.overlays[i].bounds.ne.lat + ",0");
        xw.writeString(result.overlays[i].bounds.sw.lng + "," + result.overlays[i].bounds.ne.lat + ",0");
        xw.writeEndElement();
        xw.writeEndElement();
        xw.writeEndElement();
      }
      if (result.overlays[i].type == "circle") {
        //its a polygon, approximate a circle by a circular 64 sided polygon.
        xw.writeStartElement('outerBoundaryIs');
        xw.writeStartElement('LinearRing');
        xw.writeStartElement("coordinates");
        var d2r = Math.PI / 180; // degrees to radians 
        var r2d = 180 / Math.PI; // radians to degrees 
        var earthsradius = 6378137; // 6378137 is the radius of the earth in meters
        var dir = 1; // clockwise

        var points = 64;

        // find the raidus in lat/lon 
        var rlat = (result.overlays[i].radius / earthsradius) * r2d;
        var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(result.overlays[i].center.lat * d2r);

        var extp = new Array();
        if (dir == 1) {
          var start = 0;
          var end = points + 1
        } // one extra here makes sure we connect the line
        else {
          var start = points + 1;
          var end = 0
        }
        for (var j = start;
          (dir == 1 ? j < end : j > end); j = j + dir) {
          var theta = Math.PI * (j / (points / 2));
          ey = result.overlays[i].center.lng + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
          ex = result.overlays[i].center.lat + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
          xw.writeString(ey + "," + ex + ",0");
        }
        xw.writeEndElement();
        xw.writeEndElement();
        xw.writeEndElement();
      } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < result.overlays[i].paths.length; j++) {
          if (j == 0) {
            xw.writeStartElement('outerBoundaryIs');
          } else {
            xw.writeStartElement('innerBoundaryIs');
          }
          xw.writeStartElement('LinearRing');
          xw.writeStartElement("coordinates");
          for (var k = 0; k < result.overlays[i].paths[j].length; k++) {
            xw.writeString(result.overlays[i].paths[j][k].lng + "," + result.overlays[i].paths[j][k].lat + ",0");
          }
          xw.writeEndElement();
          xw.writeEndElement();
          xw.writeEndElement();
        }
      }
      xw.writeEndElement();

    } else if (result.overlays[i].type == "polyline") {
      xw.writeStartElement('LineString');
      xw.writeElementString('extrude', '1');
      xw.writeElementString('altitudeMode', 'relativeToGround');
      xw.writeStartElement("coordinates");
      for (var j = 0; j < result.overlays[i].path.length; j++) {
        xw.writeString(result.overlays[i].path[j].lng + "," + result.overlays[i].path[j].lat + ",0");
      }
      xw.writeEndElement();
      xw.writeEndElement();

    }

    xw.writeEndElement(); // END PlaceMarker
  }

  xw.writeEndElement();
  xw.writeEndElement();
  xw.writeEndDocument();

  var xml = xw.flush(); //generate the xml string
  xw.close(); //clean the writer
  xw = undefined; //don't let visitors use it, it's closed
  //set the xml
  document.getElementById('kmlString').value = xml;
}
```